# Speed up script

Tags: bash, awk

Which shell command is the fastest way to parse through millions of lines of text. Currently I'm using GREP in my script but it takes hours upon hours to finish.

---

Sample Input:

```
May  1 2014 00:00:00 Allow
May  1 2014 00:00:00 Allow
May  1 2014 01:00:00 Deny
May  1 2014 01:00:00 Deny
May  1 2014 02:00:00 Allow
May  1 2014 02:00:00 Deny
```

---

Sample Output:

(where "2" in line one is 'grep -c "allow" ' and "0" is 'grep -c "deny" ')

```
May 1 2014 00:00:00,2,0
May 1 2014 01:00:00,0,2
May 1 2014 02:00:00,1,1
```

---

Comment: I donno what you are trying to do.

Comment: See if there's another command like sed or awk that's faster than GREP for parsing million of lines of text.

Comment: There is a detailed discussion on grep here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913014/grepping-a-huge-file-80gb-any-way-to-speed-it-up

Comment: You're adding ***two*** extra numbers but you haven't explained what they mean (your line about allow/deny only explains one... and 0-2 is three options, so it doesn't explain it at all). Please [edit] and furnish us with more information.

Comment: It's just explaining what that one and zero are in the sample data. It could potentially be millions of allowed or denied.

Comment: The first represents allow and the second represents deny.so for time 00 00 00, there are two allows and zero deny so the desired output look like 2,0.

Comment: You could use `sort | uniq -c` to get closer to your desired output. With your data snippet, it shows:  

      2 May  1 2014 00:00:00 Allow  

      2 May  1 2014 01:00:00 Deny  

      1 May  1 2014 02:00:00 Allow   

      1 May  1 2014 02:00:00 Deny  

Sorry about the formatting. The 1st column is the count

Answer (score 2):

Move away from regular expressions. They're slow (in every language) and they're far more than we need here for what amounts to simple substring comparisons.

- Take a substring of 0:20 as the first key
- Take the substring of 21:22 (single char) as the boolean outcome for the second key
- The value of that combination should be an integer that you just increment each time you see it.

I've implemented that idea below in Python:

```
data = {}
with open("file", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        key = line[0:20]
        allowed = int(line[21:22] != "A")

        if not key in data:
            data[key] = [0,0]
        data[key][allowed] += 1

for key, val in data.items():
    print('%s,%d,%d' % (key, val[0], val[1]))
```

No idea how that performs but give it a shot. If that's slower, convert it to C++ (a bit more of a PITA, which is why I'm using Python!) and that should rip through your data. It's not tough programming but it's what's required for optimal speed.

---

A little refactoring, harder to port unless you have an equivalent to `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(lambda: [0,0])
with open("file", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        key = line[0:20]
        allowed = int(line[21:22] != "A")
        data[key][allowed] += 1

for key, val in data.items():
    print('%s,%d,%d' % (key, val[0], val[1]))
```

And a Python implementation of a hybrid of  steeldriver's and my ideas. This is probably the most memory efficient you'll get and it's using substring comparison rather than a regex extraction so should be nippy. **It required sorted input though.**

```
last = ""
score = [0,0]

with open("file", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        key = line[0:20]
        allowed = int(line[21:22] != "A")

        if key and key != last:
            print '%s,%d,%d' % (last, score[0], score[1])
            score = [0,0]
            last = key

        score[allowed] += 1

print '%s,%d,%d' % (last, score[0], score[1])
```

---

### Benchmarking

In the interest of getting some of this tested (for my own curiosity, as much as anything else) I decided to do a little benchmarking on a 2,400,000 record file that covers 2400 separate dates.

I used the following Python script to generate a big file with random Allow/Deny endings:

```
import itertools, datetime, random

CHOICES = ['Allow', 'Deny']

with open("file", "w") as f:
    for _ in itertools.repeat(None, 2400):
        epoch = random.randint(1, 1404226041)
        d = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch)
        print d
        dstr = d.strftime('%b %d %Y %X')

        for _ in itertools.repeat(None, 1000):
            f.write('%s %s\n' % (dstr, CHOICES[random.randint(0,1)]))
```

This was about a thousand times faster than the Bash equivalent (see the revision log) and gives us a diverse log file to play with. It's unsorted so the two benchmarks that need collated input (3 and 4 below) are using a separate sorted version (`sort file > file-sorted` which took 0m4.253s to complete).

1. My first: 0m1.544s
2. My refactor with `defaultdict`: 0m1.413s
3. Steeldriver's `awk`: 0m5.168s + 0m4.253s sorting
4. My Python reimplementation of #3: 0m1.489s + 0m4.253s sorting

I repeated the generation with 2.4million distinct dates (should push my first two to their limits). This sort took 0m6.999s. I've also added `pypy` timings for the Python versions.

1. 0m11.589s (0m7.080s in `pypy`)
2. 0m11.307s (0m7.087s in `pypy`)
3. 0m8.652s + 0m6.999s
4. 0m6.586s + 0m6.999s (0m1.566s in `pypy`)

### Analysis and results

- On small keysets, 1 and 2 both perform best. `pypy` helps on larger keysets.
- 4 is faster than 3's `awk` largely because we're not regexing
- 4 is fastest and has the lowest footprint but only if the data comes pre-sorted
- 2 is fastest if we have jumbled data
- External sorting is *really slow*.

Comment: Just saw this, awesome recommendation! Would this be faster than fgrep which is fixed expression?

Comment: @Roboman1723 I don't think so. fgrep's Aho–Corasick string matching algo is geared at multiple pattern matches while we're not really doing that here. I haven't benched any of this. If I were you I'd check to see if the Python stands up at all and if it does, reimplement it in C (or run it through Pypy) and see how that does.

Comment: @Roboman1723 If you edit your question to include the original I can upload a comparison.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to guess whether it might be more efficient since you haven't posted enough detail about what you're doing now, but **if the data is sorted in timestamp order** I would suggest an algorithm something like

- accumulate the `Allow` and `Deny` counts until the time stamp changes (or we reach the end of input)
- print the result and (if we haven't reached end of input) reset the counts

In awk, you could do that as something like

```
awk '

FNR==1 {t = $1FS$2FS$3FS$4}

$1FS$2FS$3FS$4 == t {
  a += $5=="Allow" ? 1 : 0
  d += $5=="Deny" ? 1 : 0
}

$1FS$2FS$3FS$4 != t {
  printf "%s,%d,%d\n",t,a,d
  a = $5=="Allow" ? 1 : 0
  d = $5=="Deny" ? 1 : 0
  t = $1FS$2FS$3FS$4
}

END {printf "%s,%d,%d\n",t,a,d}

' input
```

Comment: Took me more than a minute to work out what was going on in here but I like it. It does require that the data is sorted though. Might be a worthy trade-off because it'll have pretty low memory requirements too.

Comment: Thanks @Oli you are correct about the requirement for sorted data - I have added a caveat acccordingly